# Unable to call jQuery function from class file in C# project

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am working on C# project. On masterpage,I have a jquery function named "**myfunction**" .

While trying to call this function from a class file I am getting error on browser console "**Uncaught ReferenceError: myfunctionis not defined**".

```
function myfunction(){
// code
}

 string script = "";
 script = "<SCRIPT language='javascript'>myfunction(); </SCRIPT>";                

 var obj = ((Object)(HttpContext.Current.Handler));                
 Type scriptType = obj.GetType();
 ClientScriptManager cs = ((Page)(HttpContext.Current.Handler)).ClientScript;
 cs.RegisterStartupScript(scriptType, "alert", script.ToString());
```

While working on any C# website, I can call this function from class file as well but here getting error. Even if I use update panel then function executes but without update panel its not executing.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you try to execute the function at the global context using your browser's console?

Comment: its executing fine, when I directly run on browser colsole..

Comment: Please clarify: It's a javascript function, isn't it ? Does jquery have anything to do with this ?  What are you trying to say about class files, do you mean it's not working from codebehind file ? When are you getting errors and when is it working ?

Comment: its a jQuery function and I am trying to call it from code behind file..

Comment: You can't really call jQuery (or javascript) from C# code. I still think you should give us a better explanation of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the type on the script declaration:

```
script = "<SCRIPT language='text/javascript'>myfunction(); </SCRIPT>";
```

Remove the redundant ToString() call:

```
cs.RegisterStartupScript(scriptType, "alert", script);
```

And make sure myfunction() is output on the HTML before your script is inserted.

Comment: Post the HTML so we can help you.

Comment: when I use update panel then it works fine, means it call jquery function before it loads the page containing that function..have tried setTimeOut as well but not working..

Comment: Post the HTML so we can help you.